# changing class name of a link in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have hrefs in my page and I want to change the name of the class name of the link that is clicked . But my script is changing all the class of the links. Is there a way without giving ids to the links?

my script is as follows:

```
$('myLink a').attr('class', 'newClassName');

<div id="myLink">
<a class="text"><span id="wordBlock-0">house</span></a>
<a class="text"><span id="wordBlock-0">house</span></a>
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want working with id of an element must in selector use **#** and if you want working with class of an element must use **.**

```
$("#myLink a").click(function () {
 $("#myLink a").attr('class', 'newClassName');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `addClass()` and `removeClass` methods

```
$('myLink a').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('newClassName');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myLink a').click(function(){
   $(this).attr('class', 'newClassName');
   return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try binding a click event, and then using `this` to refer to the clicked element.

```
$('myLink a').click(function(){
   $(this).attr('class', 'newClassName');
});
```